# Does WebDriver copy the specified over to a temporary profile?

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to use WebDriver to remotely firefox 8, but I seem to be running into some issues. My main problem is that I specify a profile to use both from the actual test code itself and by using the -Dwebdriver.user.profile flag when starting selenium server. However, no matter what selenium server always seems to create a temp profile that has all the certificates but does not have any of the extensions. Any one else run into this problem or have any suggestions as to where to debug? The reason I ask this is because with FireFox 8 we have the setup addons screen that pops up on a first time launch of a profile it prompts you to select which add-ons you want to enable which causes the test to fail.

Comment: My crystal ball is #000, so actual code would be very helpful.

Comment: I have issue with FirefoxProfile and FireFox 8.
I fixed this simply downgrading to FireFox 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I have worked around the problem by creating a new profile through web driver and setting the profile properties i need programatically, from what I am seeing it doesn't seem as though you are able to modifying the profile properties of an existing profile but you can edit one that you create yourself. But as far as the question at hand goes, for firefox even if you are using an exisitng profile webdriver copies this into a temporary profile to launch the browser through if you are performing the automation remotely, but if you are launching the browser locally specifying an installed profile then webdriver uses that actual profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into selenium svn commit log.
In Trunk the following commit is exist:

```
Revision: 14639
Author: simon.m.stewart
Date: 18:49:52 PM, Wednesday, November 09, 2011
Message:
SimonStewart: Native events on Windows for Firefox 8, and adding the chrome.manifest entries for linux too.
----
Modified : /trunk/WebDriver.sln
Modified : /trunk/cpp/build.desc
Added : /trunk/cpp/prebuilt/Win32/Release/webdriver-firefox-latest.dll
Added : /trunk/cpp/webdriver-firefox/webdriver-firefox-latest.vcxproj
Modified : /trunk/javascript/firefox-driver/build.desc
Modified : /trunk/javascript/firefox-driver/extension/chrome.manifest
```

Unfortunately we use selenium version 2.10 in which only FireFox 7 is supported.
And this revision is not included into tag 2.10.
And we failed to launch tests on FireFox 8.

So try to update your selenium or downgrade your Firefox.

Comment: I'm actually running the latest version of selenium and unfortunately I need to run this on FireFox 8. I'm going to take a look at the source for webdriver as soon as i can and post back my findings.